# Gitlab-ci - Services

Tags: docker, service, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a service and some stages in my yml.
I only need to use the service for a specific stage. Unfortunately, however, the service loads the image for each stage, lengthening the execution times. Is there a way to prevent a service from being performed or used by every stage inside the ci?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, but it sounds like you defined the service(s) at the "default" level (that applies to every job in the pipeline) instead of the job level (that applies just to that job). Take a look at the examples in the docs (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ciyml):

**Services for entire pipeline**

```yaml
default:
  image: ruby:2.6

  services:
    - postgres:11.7

  before_script:
    - bundle install

test:
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

Here, the `postgres:11.7` service will be run for each and every job in a pipeline because it's defined outside of any jobs, in the "default" configuration. If only setting one keyword, it might also look like this:

```yaml
services:
  - postgres:11.7

test:
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

**Service for a specific job**

```yaml
test:2.6:
  image: ruby:2.6
  services:
    - postgres:11.7
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec

test:2.7:
  image: ruby:2.7
  services:
    - postgres:12.2
  script:
    - bundle exec rake spec
```

Here, each job has its own `services` and `image` configuration, so the service will only be used for that job, and once it finishes, the service will be terminated. This is useful if say you wanted to test your code against multiple versions of a database, etc.

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you very much for your answer! I've also checked the documentation and cosnider this solution (which is great), i was just asking my self if there were another possible solution with, for example, an opt-out variable to set. But, as i said, it's perfect, Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help! If this answer or any other one solved your issue, you can upvote it and mark it as Accepted.